How can I add ffmpeg to a .NET MAUI project for Android/iOS?
I have looking for solutions but just don't understand exactly what to do. There are several nuget packages that seem to be wrappers for ffmpeg but don't actually include ffmpeg itself such as FFMpegCore. I have been trying to follow the steps to build for Android from ffmpeg-kit, but it keeps failing and I am at a loss. Forgive my ignorance, but why is there no straightforward way to add ffmpeg to a .NET MAUI project that can be used on iOS/Android?

What are actually trying to do?

@Jason FFMpegCore assumes you already have ffmpeg installed in order to work, so I'm trying to add ffmpeg to my .NET MAUI project. I'm a little in over my head with this and the process is confusing.

@codybchaplin correct me if I am wrong, but you don't really have to build it to use it, do you? I see 50MB .aar file sitting in maven, waiting to be downloaded. One binding library and the problem is half solved.

@H.A.H. Where can I find this .aar file? I'm not familiar with maven.

@codybchaplin In the link, that you have placed in your question, you have section "using", And there you can see how it can be used in Android. But instead adding this link to the repo, you can actually go there, and download the aar file. Then you need to build binding library. I cannot say it more simply than that.

@H.A.H. I assume you're referring to the files found here?
https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/releases/tag/v6.0

@codybchaplin Did you manage to get this working?

@ledragon I did not, I ended up not needing it my case.
